# JSON Column formatting : retrieve view ID or param in URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, view, url, json-formatting, column-formatting

I need to retrieve view ID (or Name) to format a SharePoint list column with JSON formatting.

Or at least I should be able get the correct query parameter of the URL.

Is there any variable available to do so ?

(I don't want to use a SPFX column extension).

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Create [SPFx Field Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) so you could get the view id by `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer to your question is **No**.

Currently there is no variable/function available to get the current View ID/Name while using JSON formatting on column.

For more information on column formatting, check below documentation:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).